# ConcurrentHashMap remove() using thread A while iterating using thread B

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

As I understand, `put()`, `clear()` and `remove()` are provided by `ConcurrentHashMap` and it is thread safe operation without using any locks.

In `ConcurrentHashMap`, there are different segments and for each segment there are several hash buckets.

`Clear()` and `put()` are thread safe because `clear()` just clear the reference to the hash chain for that bucket but the hash chain is still there, so if **thread A** is iterating over it, it will not be affected but `clear()` from **thread B**. `Put()` will always put a new node at the beginning of the hash chain for that bucket, so it is fine also.

However,What I don't understand is that why `remove()` will be thread safe? For example, the hash bucket is **bucket->A->B->C->D->E** and **thread A** calls `remove(C)`, the mechanism provided by the implementation of the `ConcurrentHashMap` is to copy A, B into a next linked list but in reverse order **bucket->B->A->D-E** and then make A.next to the original **D->E** which result in  **bucket->B->A->D-E**.

Why this is thread safe? What if `thread B` is currently iterating over element A and then `thread A` calls remove(C). Looks like it will break?

Comment: What kind of "breaking" are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, remove() clones HashEntry elements up to removed element, not modifies old ones. So you get

B*->A*->D->E in bucket, but original

A->B->C-^ sequence is not touched.

You can be sure that A.equals(A*) == false, even though they will have equal keys and equal values. But that's not a problem for iterator as it simply uses already aquired entry A to move on.

P.S. ConcurrentHashMap uses locks on bucket level for modifications. It's not lock-free.

Comment: Perfect, make perfect sense.